# How to post a COMMENT with FB application profile photo?

Tags: facebook, api, comments, access-token

It is possible for a 'facebook application' to post a COMMENT on a POST when there is a valid ACCESS_TOKEN. API call for the same is: **/xyz_profile_id/comments/?access_token=...**

ACCESS_TOKEN being generated by allowing the "facebook application" to get access to xyz_profile_id. The post done will have default FROM ID as xyz_profile_id showing his/her profile photo along with the comment.

**My requirement is this:** How to change the FROM ID as appilcation_id so that the profile photo of the application is shown beside the posted comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information on what you are doing and how you are doing it. Not sure about 'FROM ID as application_id' requirement.

E.g. posting comment to a post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<post_id>/comments?access_token=<token>&method=post&message=hi
```

will generate a story like this:

[image: post comment story]

How do you want to change this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need to authenticate your session with an application access_token, as opposed to a user access_token.  Make sure the application has been installed on that particular page you want to update comments on.

Read more: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/